# Loop for regressions in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to run a loop to create 4 separate regressions and store them using:

```
for (i in 1:4){
    reg_[i] <- lm(Y ~ W, data = subset(df_train, ntile == [i]))
}
```

But something is wrong and they aren't being stored as `reg_1` , `reg_2`, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop a linear regression over multiple subsets of a factor variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411852/how-to-loop-a-linear-regression-over-multiple-subsets-of-a-factor-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `assign` to create multiple objects in the global environment

```
for (i in 1:4){
   assign(paste0("reg_", i),  lm(Y ~ W, data = subset(df_train, ntile == [i])))
 }
```